# Unable to locate .npm/_logs/ folder on mac

Tags: macos, npm

I am building a vuejs app and when I an `npm run dev`, it gave me an error something like this:

https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Screenshot-2020-02-15-at-1.16.31-AM.png

Now I want to locate the `/Users/keith-mac/.npm/_logs/2020-02-15T06_02_56_692Z-debug.log` file (to see what went wrong while running my app) on my MacBook Air, but when I navigate to `/Users/keith-mac/`, I am not able to locate the `.npm` folder.

I do not want any help with why I am getting an error. I just want help with locating the `.npm` folder in my machine.

Comment: Can you run `find $HOME -name "*debug.log"` ?

Comment: A file or folder whose name begins with a dot (`.`), such as `.npm` is hidden. Since macOS Sierra you can type `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `.` in the Finder to reveal the hidden items. If you have an earlier macOS, then launch the _Terminal_ and run: `cat /Users/keith-mac/.npm/_logs/2020-02-15T06_02_56_692Z-debug.log` to read the contents.